# Installing Julia packages using a .toml file?

Tags: installation, julia

I am totally new to Julia!

I would like to install a large number of packages for a project I'm joining.

The project comes with a "Project.toml" file

It seems like there should be a nice way to install all the packages I need for the project, perhaps using the Project.toml file

However, I have not yet found any site that indicates how I might be able to do this.

Could anyone please let me know if what I am doing is possible, and if so, point me to a reference that would show how?

Answer (score 14):

If your Project.toml is located in a folder, like `myproject/Project.toml`, you can simply start Julia with `julia --project=/path/to/myproject`, and it will automatically detect the Project.toml file in `myproject`.

The first time you activate this project, in the REPL, you can switch to `Pkg` mode by typing `]`, and type the command `instantiate`.  This will cause the package manager to download and install all of the packages listed in `Project.toml` and their dependencies.

Another way to switch between projects during interactive use is to run `activate /path/to/myproject` in Pkg-mode in the REPL.

Comment: If i don't want to start Julia, just install the packages. is that possible?

Comment: @Sanidhya Singh, if you don't want the interactive interface, you can run `julia --project=/path/to/myproject -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate()'`.  It is necessary to run the julia executable one way or another, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was looking for something like `pip install -r requirements.txt`  but looks like you need to invoke Julia code directly to setup the environment

Answer (score 2):

How to install julia packages from a Project.toml

First, you will have navigate to the folder containing your Project.toml.

`cd ../your-folder-containing-the-project.toml-file`

in your terminal:

`julia --project=.`

`]`

`instantiate`

or

`julia --project=. -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.instantiate()`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers went already to the point, but I want to add another important aspect.

If this project comes "only" with a `Project.toml` file, you will be able to install "sone version" of these packages, eventualy the `Project.toml` may also give you a range of versions known to work with the project you have been given.

But if this project comes also with a `Manifest.toml` file you will be able to recreate on your pc the *exact* environment, will all the exact versions of all dependent packages recursivelly, of the guy that passed you the project, using the ways desctibed in detail in the other answers (e.g. `] activate [folder]; instantiate`).